# Is there a way to reverse camera zoom action in Blender?

Tags: camera

I'd really like to set up the camera to behave 100% like Maya. The zoom function is inverted with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd>  in Blender which is beyond annoying. Is there a way to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

You can change it under Edit > Preferences

[image: MouseZoom]